# Meaning of @method && @Command annotation in aws php sdk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was looking into the codebase of Amazon AWS PHP sdk and found that, several methods in comments are declared as @command such as the one below(link: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Aws/S3/S3Client.php):

```
* @method Model getObject(array $args = array()) {@command S3 GetObject}
```

Can anyone please explain how this actually works? I want to know the actual working mechanism inside 'getObject' method call. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods such as `getObject()` are dynamic methods instead of static methods. The *real* call is `getCommand('GetObject')`, but the class's `__call()` method handles the real work.

Every service in the SDK has a [Model Definition](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Aws/S3/Resources/s3-2006-03-01.php). The `getCommand()` method takes the inputs and maps them to the Model Definition and makes the right request.

So, think of `getObject()` as a convenience method, that is constructed dynamically instead of statically.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.